# Sticky menu conflict

Tags: menu, sticky, mmenu

we are trying to integrate mmenu with WordPress. In principle everything works perfectly, but when we make the sticky menu does not work, neither in the PC nor mobile version.
The url is: https://en-desarrollo.eu/pruebas/

we have added mmenu and integrated it using the usual way and everything is fine. The problem is when we set the menu as sticky, it stops working.